# Can child div opacity be lesser than parent div?

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to achieve this (as shown in below pic). 
[image]

I have background image in the container, Another div is overlay it with black color opacity. But I don't want my child div container be affected by that overlay div.

Here's the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Rp5BN/1274/

```css
#parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/);
}
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#child {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the background-color and opacity of the child element.

`background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)` adds a white colored background with an opacity of 25% which gives the effect you are trying to achieve. Modify the opacity and rgb values to get the effect of the output screenshot(Hope I have almost did that :D)

```css
#parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/);
}
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#child {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); /* Add */
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that you applied opacity on white color, so technically u r applying white opacity layer on black opacity layer. But what I want is exact transparent bg image. ?? Any approriate tip regarding it ??

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible with CSS. Once the opacity of the parent is set, the child will also have the opacity effected. You can try to create a JS solution.

Comment: ok, I wil look forward to that, but if come across any such js, do share. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I have not come across that as well. But the logic is to find the `parent's (width and height)` - `child's (width and height)` and apply the opacity only to it. That means you need to detect the parent's view-able/visible area.